# To get a value in JavaScript which is set in HttpRequest Object in Middle Layer?

Tags: java, html, struts

Can anyone suggest me how to get a value from my variable, in JavaScript, which is set in `HttpRequest` Object in Middle Layer?

I am doing something like this `servletRequest.setAttribute("retriggerRequest", retriggerRequest);`.
I want to check `retriggerRequest` value in my JavaScript and work accordingly. Is there any way out? Any suggestions would be helpful :) Thanks!!

**Note: Its a post request so I can't get it from the url.**

Comment: Are you using Struts? Which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hidden textfield for it.

```
<input name='myvalue' type="hidden" value=${myvalue} />
```